# AngularJS Directive fetched templateUrl not working

Tags: angularjs

i am totally beginner on using AngularJS1

What i've done right now is to create a custom directive of my own with the following code:

```
var ui = angular.module('ui',[ 'core' ]);

ui.directive( 'shTag', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            text: '=',
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.type = attrs.type;
        },
        templateUrl: config.base_url + "/directive/tag",
    }
});
```

As you can see templateUrl is fetched within my backend and it just return html as a response.

This is the response of the request:

```
<span class="" > [[ scope.text ]]</span>
```

However when it did not display scope.text value.

Note i used [[ ]] as my interpolator.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: use [[ text ]] instead

Comment: i'm not familiar with "interpolator" but the basic way to display scope data in the view is `{{text}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you're not using a `controllerAs: 'scope'` syntax, you don't have to use `scope.text`, just use `[[ text ]]`.

everything on $scope is available on inside your directive.

(plus: have a look at components in angular 1.5, they add some syntax sugar and are pretty sexy to work with)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your $interpolateProvider correctly configured to make `[[ ]]` work properly, use `[[text]]` as Alainlb mentioned, and ensure that you have the attribute value 'text' set up on your tag usage like so:

```
<sh-tag text="'display me to the world'"></sh-tag>
```

Because you are using an isolate scope, the only way `text` will have a value is if you assign a value to that attribute. Note I've used a string here, but that could have been a variable on the parent scope.

I'd also recommend you check your network in an inspector to ensure that the request is going through (the url is 100% correct) for the templateUrl.

Other than that, everything looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you configure the interpolation correctly before the template is fetched. (During bootstrap, before the rest of the application is running!)
As you are just getting started I recommend to stick to the defaults until you are familiar with the concepts and how to debug problems.